# Pressure on the Free Surface (water wave)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

Small-amplitude two-dimensional waves disturb the free surface of an incompressible, irrotational fluid with a pressure p(x, y, t) and a velocity potential $φ(x, y, t)$ which satisfies Laplace’s equation. The free surface, given by $y = η(x,t)$, is at constant atmospheric pressure pa and the fluid is of infinite depth.
In terms of $φ$ and $η$, what is the kinematic boundary condition at the free surface? Starting from the Euler equations, show that φ may be chosen such that
$$\frac{∂φ}{∂t}+\frac{1}{2}|∇φ|^2+gy+\frac{p−p_a}{\rho} =0$$
You are given that the jump in pressure across the free surface is given by
$$p−p_a=-T\frac{∂^2η}{∂x^2}/{(1+(\frac{∂η}{∂x})^2)}^\frac{3}{2} $$
on y = η, where T is the surface tension. Show that, when the problem is linearised by neglecting quadratic terms, the boundary conditions are simplified to
$$\frac{∂φ}{∂y}=\frac{∂η}{∂t}, \frac{∂φ}{∂t} + gη − T \frac{∂^2η}{∂x^2} =0$$
on $y = 0$.

I understand the first boundary condition but how to do the second one, obviously using the free surface pressure jump.

Answer (score 1):

The kinematic boundary condition simply states that the substantial derivative of the function $f = y - \eta(x,t)$ is zero (that is, the interface is a fluid surface). Therefore, it is required:

$$ Df/Dt =  -\eta_t - \varphi_x \eta_x + \varphi_y = 0 $$

at the free surface.